# Definition of Dukkha

Tags: dukkha, definition

What is the precise meaning of the word "dukkha", often translated as "suffering" in Buddhism?

Is it correct to say that Buddhism gives a method to get rid of **all** sufferings, including the most basic physical suffering (=illness/pain etc.)? So in that case even if some disease has no cure with our current medicine, Buddhism somehow has a way to free us from the pain of this disease?

Please if possible provide a precise reference.

Comment: There is no such thing as "physical suffering". All suffering is mental. There is physical pain but physical pain is not suffering.

Comment: i answered your question at What is the most accurate translation of the word 'dukkha'?

Comment: "Birth is dukkha, aging is dukkha, death is dukkha; sorrow, lamentation, pain, [...]"
"And what is pain? Whatever is experienced as bodily pain, bodily discomfort, pain or discomfort born of bodily contact, that is called pain."
That's what the link of SarathW says. So physical pain is suffering according to this reference.

Comment: The Buddha summarised all dukkha as attachment. "In short, the five clinging-aggregates are dukkha." The words "in short" or "in summary" (Pali: "saṃkhittena") means all dukkha is attachment. You should learn the literal meaning of the teachings rather than impute your own misinterpretations upon them. The scriptures say in many places "sorrow, lamentation, pain, grief, & despair" are caused by attachment; such as in SN 12.2: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.002.than.html

Comment: Okay let me copy/paste two citations, from the Buddha himself (I am assuming the english translation is accurate):
1) "Birth is dukkha, aging is dukkha, death is dukkha; sorrow, lamentation, pain, grief, & despair are dukkha;"
2) "Whatever is experienced as bodily pain, bodily discomfort, pain or discomfort born of bodily contact, that is called pain."

Okay, so then 1) and 2) combined give the implication: "bodily pain is Dukkha". Where am I interpreting anything?

Comment: yes, the noble truth ends with the words:  "IN SHORT, the five clinging-aggregates are dukkha."

Comment: So do we agree that pain is part of Dukkha? Hence cessation of Dukkha implies cessation of physical suffering?

Comment: there is no such thing as physical suffering. only the unenlightened believe in physical suffering. buddha said all suffering is attachment

Comment: Then why does the buddha talk explicitely about "bodily pain, bodily discomfort"?

Answer (score 0):

"Birth is dukkha, aging is dukkha, death is dukkha; sorrow, lamentation, pain, grief, & despair are dukkha; association with the unbeloved is dukkha; separation from the loved is dukkha; not getting what is wanted is dukkha. **In short, the five clinging-aggregates are dukkha."**

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca1/dukkha.html

Comment: Great, this answers the first question. What about the other two questions?